# If points $( k+3 , 2-k)$, $ (k, 1-k)$ and $(3, 4+k)$ are collinear, find the value of $k$

Tags: geometry

> If the points $( k+3 , 2-k)$, $(k, 1-k)$ and $(3, 4+k)$ are collinear,
>   find the value of $k$.

Can someone please hint at how to start this question? I've so far tried finding the gradients but no luck. thanks!

Comment: hint:
$$
    (k+3,2-k)-(k,1-k) \propto (k+3,2-k)-(3,4+k)
$$

Comment: What does that symbol (infinite-like) mean in this context?

Comment: @DonAntonio: One side is a multiple of the other, AFAIK.

Comment: [Collinearity of points whose coordinates are given](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity#Collinearity_of_points_whose_coordinates_are_given)

Comment: Ok @Gigili , that makes sense here. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, sorry, it means "is proportional to". Also, it is slightly incorrect, since $\propto$ is not symmetric, and one side could be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Three points $\,P_1,P_2,P_3\,$in the real plane are collinear iff the slope between $\,P_2,P_1\,$ equals the slope between $\,P_3,P_2\,$ , so in our case it must be

$$\frac{1-k-2+k}{k-k-3}=\frac{4+k-1+k}{3-k}\iff \frac13=\frac{2k+3}{3-k}$$

Well, now solve for $\,k\,$ ...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to check the collinearity of $3$ points, some of them are:

$A( k+3 , 2-k), B(k, 1-k)$ and $C(3, 4+k)$

1. If $3$ points are collinear then area of the triangle made by them is zero.
2. $AB=t.AC$

$\Delta ABC=\dfrac 12\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{array} \right|=0$
$$\dfrac 12\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
k+3 & 2-k & 1 \\
k & 1-k & 1 \\
3 & 4+k & 1\end{array} \right|=0$$
After solving this determinant value of $k=\dfrac {-6}{7}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If these points are on the plane $ x $ $ y $. If they are collinear they are on the same straight line. Soon they must satisfy the equation of the line 
$$
\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
If $(x_1,y_1)=( k+3 , 2-k)$, $(x_2,y_2)=(k, 1-k)$ and $(x_3,y_3)=(3, 4+k)$ are collinear  then 
$$
\frac{y_3-y_1}{x_3-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$